# Not able to send file to group chat openfire

Tags: xmpp, file-transfer, openfire, asmack

i am creating a rooms in openfire.

want to send files in a room so that it can distribute that file to all room occupants.

I am done with one to one file transfer by following this post :

http://harryjoy.me/2012/08/18/file-transfer-in-android-with-asmack-and-openfire /

Now i am not able to send the file in a group. What am I doing is instead of sending file to user, I am just replacing username with group name :

```
    OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer("usre2@myHost/Smack");
```

to =>

```
    OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer("groupname@conference.myHost");
```

Comment: got any solution brother..?

Answer (score 0):

OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer("groupname@conference.myHost/groupmember");

Comment: in above code , i have to explicitly give names of group members which i dont have. whoever has joined the group, the file should be sent to them.

Comment: groupmember will be nickname or whole username ("usre2@myHost/Smack") ??

Comment: it is not working for me... do u mean to send each member separately??

Comment: Groupmember only nickname & need to send separately

Comment: Hi there, I followed your suggestion but i got problem in receiving the file from group chat. the filetransferrequest method is not invoked but normal chat works normally. could you help me over here?